# jQuery click event with fat-arrow function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery's click event with fat arrow function can be confusing. `Event.target` is not what You expect. Here is code sample:

```
constructor() {
    $("a.nav-link").click((e)=>{
        this.func($(e.target).data("target"));
    })
}

private func(target: string) {
    console.log(target);
}

<a class="nav-link" data-target="search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
```

Some times event.target is `i` element - not expected `a` tag.

I have workaround:

```
constructor() {
    let _this = this;
    $("a.nav-link").click(function (e) {
        _this.func($(this).data("target"));
    })
}
```

Is there a solution working with fat arrow function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get away with the first implementation - one of the stated capabilities of the arrow function syntax is the [lexical binding of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this), so `this` is not what you expect here, as you override jQuery's handler function `this` binding.
This matters as instead of using `e.target` you'll be better off with `$(this)` (but you won't be able to get the right `this` for your purposes - you need `this` to point at your class instance).

That said, there is no relation to the event parameter's properties. It's passed as-is regardless of the function context.

Your "workaround" has two parts: using a `function` statement, and retrieving the bound element via `$(this)`. The later is actually the proper way of dealing with your issue, and the former allows you to refer to both contexts inside the function.

Its a perfectly valid solution, I say go with it, and don't try to force a solution with arrow functions where they don't fit.

Comment: And there is no usefull property in event object?

Comment: what *"useful property"* are you looking for? it seems like you achieved your goal by referencing `$(this)`